# Python: How to send mails via smtp relay?

Tags: email, smtp, smtplib

I am following this procedure [Option 3 in SMTP Relay Office365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365#option-3-configure-a-connector-to-send-mail-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365-smtp-relay) When I done every procedure said in the article. After that when I run my python app with

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('XXMYMAILXX-com.mail.protection.outlook.com.', 25)
s.starttls()
s.login("john@XXMYMAILXX.com", "mypassword")
```

when I run this piece of code I get an error

```
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server
```

What am I missing here?

The steps I followed in the article are

1. Added the IP address where my python is being run to my mail connector
2. Added the TXT record with the IP address to spf records.

Comment: The error message simply means the server does not support (this mode of) authentication, or perhaps that you need to send `EHLO` before it will.

Comment: I send `EHLO` still the same error

Comment: The instructions you link to don't seem to be about regular SMTP relay. A section earlier on the page says you have to separately enable SMTP AUTH but it seems to describe a different scenario, albeit one which seems better aligned with what you seem to be trying to do. Why are you not using the first option in Microsoft's documentation?

Comment: The first option doesn't work because the client uses Multifactor authentication like A Authenticator app to login